# How to reload information correctly in app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, restangular

I'm developing  a Angular App using Restangular with Web Services REST, but when I change between sessions several user the information have a delay to display information. for example a view CustomerDetail with Information of User1 but when I change a User2 then it show me information of User1 and later in n seconds show information correctly the user User2.

My question is, how to reload information correctly in view?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, try reducing server calls by getting as much data at once and then create client side reload. regarding your case, when you click on some button to change users, first change a variable to "onLoad" to true and perform ng-show="onLoad" for some loading div and ng-show="!onLoad" for some other div contains users info. then when you get back your data flip "onLoad" value...